# Hyper-V Manager no longer shows my virtual machines

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit Enterprise Mode. Have been using Hyper-V Manager with a couple VMs I created without issue for a few years now. Last night my desktop rebooted after security updates were applied. Today when I open Hyper-V, my VMs are no longer displayed, and my desktop no longer appears listed in the left pane beneath "Hyper-V Manager".

I've verified that the expected services related to Hyper-V are all running, and all the boxes are selected when I look at Hyper-V from Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off.

The only option I have in Hyper-V Manager is "Connect to server". When I try to connect to my local machine, I get an error saying to check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running. As stated, it is.

Not sure what else to try to get reconnected to my virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was related to a network adapter issue on my host system. Once the networking team cleared that up, I was able to see my virtual machines again within the Hyper-V Manager.

I did have to delete the old virtual switch then create a new one, as the VMs would start up but not launch. Error was "External ethernet adapter is already bound to the Microsoft virtual switch protocol."

After creating the new switch, I had to attach it to each of my existing snapshots. After that, all was well.